# Whats $\epsilon_{ijk} $ in Vector Calculus?

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis

I've seen $\epsilon_{ijk} $  used to prove properties of the $\nabla $ operators on both scalar functions and vector fields, but I don't understand what it is. Can somebody explain what this is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol

Comment: @NickYarn Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [Levi-Civita symbol](http://Levi-Civita%20symbol) in three dimension

$$ \varepsilon_{ijk} =
  \begin{cases}
         +1 & \text{if } (i,j,k) \text{ is } (1,2,3), (2,3,1), \text{ or } (3,1,2), \\
         -1 & \text{if } (i,j,k) \text{ is } (3,2,1), (1,3,2), \text{ or } (2,1,3), \\
    \;\;\,0 & \text{if } i = j, \text{ or } j = k, \text{ or } k = i
\end{cases}$$